# removeAllChildren vs. issuing 'removeFromParent' for all nodes in self.children?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm following a SpriteKit tutorial, and for a sub-class of SKSpriteNode, they have the following code:

```
for child in children {
    child.removeFromParent()
}
```

Why use this instead of:

```
removeAllChildren
```

? To me, removeAllChildren would be the obvious choice. I know that one is asking the parent to remove all its children, and the other is asking all the children to remove themselves from their parent, and I wondered if there was one subtlety I'm missing.

For further information, this was in the Ray Wenderlich tutorial 'CatNap' which is part of a paid-for series of tutorials. The code is in a function in a subclass of SKSpriteNode and is used to change the appearance of the node by removing all the children (eyes, tail, etc.) and replacing them with a new node. Here is the function:

```
func wakeUp() {
    for child in children {
      child.removeFromParent()
    }
    texture = nil
    color = SKColor.clearColor()

    let catAwake = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "CatWakeUp")!.childNodeWithName("cat_awake")!

    catAwake.moveToParent(self)
    catAwake.position = CGPoint(x: -30, y: 100)
}
```

I did wonder if `removeAllChildren` wasn't available when the tutorial was written, but `removeallChildren` was introduced with SpriteKit in iOS 7, so that doesn't appear to be it.

Comment: No reason, the author probably just didn't know (or forgot) about `removeAllChildren`. That happens all the time in programming, that's why we have code reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced the `child.removeFromParent` loop with a single `removeAllChildren` with no apparent change in behaviour. I suspect that the author of the tutorial just didn't know that this function was available.

It's possible that if you subclass `SKNode` and override `removeFromParent`, you could introduce some custom behavior that `removeAllChildren` wouldn't action.